# Upload mysql dump on heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cleardb

I need to upload my local .sql dump into my heroku machine. I'm using MySQL db and the plugin ClearDB.

I have tried this command:

```
 mysql --host=us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com --user=MY_USER --password=MY_PASSWORD --reconnect heroku_xxxxxxxxxxxx < test.sql
```

But I get this error as response:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

What should I do now?
Thank you!

UPDATE: this is my heroku config output:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:     mysql://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net/heroku_xxxxxxxxxxx?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:             mysql2://xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net/heroku_xxxxxxxxxxx?reconnect=true
LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
MAX_THREADS:              1
MIN_THREADS:              1
RACK_ENV:                 production
RAILS_ENV:                production
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE:          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

UPDATE 2.0:

I noticed that the host was wrong so I correct it:

```
mysql --host=us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.com --user=xxxxxx --password=xxxxxx --skip-ssl --reconnect heroku_xxxxxx < test.sql
```

But I still get errors:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
WARNING: --ssl is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use --ssl-mode instead.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.com' (61)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this.

```
mysql --host=us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com --user=MY_USER --password=MY_PASSWORD --skip-ssl --reconnect heroku_xxxxxxxxxxxx < test.sql
```

I have just added --skip-ssl to it.

update:

I have noticed that now you are using "us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.com" but your actual host is "us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net" can you please try by replacing .com by .net.

Comment: Now it tells me: Access denied for user 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'@'ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal' (using password: YES), I check ten times and the user/password are right, I get them from ClearDb Dashboard...

Comment: can you run heroku config to get the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL?

Comment: I have noticed that now you are using "us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.com" but your actual host is "us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net" can you please try by replacing .com by .net.

Comment: You were right, just mistaken .com with .net. Thank you so much!